# sort using jkit

Tags: date, sorting

How to sort date using jkit?
I'm using the following code to sort. But it's not working.

```
<th data-jkit="[sort:what=text;by=date]">Birthday</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to call jquery, jkit and also activate Jkit.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.jkit.1.2.16.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').jKit();
});
</script>
</head>
```